# Error: comments.map is not a function - how to change data type?

Tags: reactjs, function, redux

I'm new to React, and I'm trying to get comments to show up on a page. I'm getting the error that comments.map is not a function, I believe because comments is the incorrect datatype. I'm having trouble figuring out how to tweak my code to make comments into an array, instead of an object. Thanks so much for your help.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
// MUI
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = (theme) => ({
  ...theme.SpreadThis,
  commentImage: {
    maxWidth: '100%',
    height: 100,
    objectFit: 'cover',
    borderRadius: '50%'
  },
  commentData: {
    marginLeft: 20
  }
});

class Comments extends Component {
  render() {
    const { comments, classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid container>
        {comments.map((comment, index) => {
          const { body, createdAt, userImage, userHandle } = comment;
          return (
            <Fragment key={createdAt}>
              <Grid item sm={12}>
                <Grid container>
                  <Grid item sm={2}>
                    <img
                      src={userImage}
                      alt="comment"
                      className={classes.commentImage}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item sm={9}>
                    <div className={classes.commentData}>
                      <Typography
                        variant="h5"
                        component={Link}
                        to={`/users/${userHandle}`}
                        color="primary"
                      >
                        {userHandle}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                        {dayjs(createdAt).format('h:mm a, MMMM DD YYYY')}
                      </Typography>
                      <hr className={classes.invisibleSeparator} />
                      <Typography variabnt="body1">{body}</Typography>
                    </div>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              {index !== comments.length - 1 && (
                <hr className={classes.visibleSeparator} />
              )}
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

Comments.propTypes = {
  comments: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Comments);
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have put the initial state of `comments` to an empty array in the higher order component. and use `comments?.map()` that `?` sign first checks if the array exists and then it will execute the `map()` function.